# no response is received while using JavaScript for password change

Tags: javascript, php

below is my script to change password. if all data is entered correctly, please wait message comes up but no further processing is received. Please help me in rectifying the error.
if i work on this script without javascript, it works fine but with javascript it becomes non-responsive.

```
<?php
include_once("check_login_status.php");
if(isset($_GET["u"])){
if(isset($_POST["email"])){
    include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['email']);
    $pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
    $pass1 = md5($_POST['pass1']);
    $pass2 = md5($_POST['pass2']);
    if($email == "" || $pass == ""||$pass1 == ""||$pass2 == ""){
        echo "login_failed";
        exit();
    } else  if($pass1 !=$pass2){echo"no match";
        exit();}

    else    
 {
    // END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $db_id = $row[0];
        $db_username = $row[1];
        $db_pass_str = $row[2];
        if($pass != $db_pass_str){      
            echo "data wrong";
            exit();
        } else if($u != $db_username){
            echo "username_mismatched";
            exit();
        }
        else {
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET password='$pass1' WHERE email='$email'";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
            echo "success";
            exit();
            }
    }
    exit();
}}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
<script>
function emptyElement(x){
    _(x).innerHTML = "";
}
function paschange(){
        var email = _("email").value;
    var pass = _("pass").value;
        var pass1 = _("pass1").value;
    var pass2 = _("pass2").value;
    if(pass == "" || pass1 == ""||pass2==""||email==""){
        _("status").innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
    } 
    else if(pass1!=pass2)
    {_("status").innerHTML = "Password dont match";
}
    else {
        _("passbtn").style.display = "none";
        _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "javat.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText == "login_failed"){
                    _("status").innerHTML = "Fields empty.";
                    _("passbtn").style.display = "block";}
                    else if(ajax.responseText == "no match"){
                        _("status").innerHTML = "password mismatched";
                    _("passbtn").style.display = "block";
                } 
                else if(ajax.responseText == "data wrong"){
                        _("status").innerHTML = "raw or pin wriong";
                    _("passbtn").style.display = "block";
                } 
                else if(ajax.responseText == "username_mismatched"){
                        _("status").innerHTML = "username didnt match with username";
                    _("passbtn").style.display = "block";
                } 
                else if(ajax.responseText == "success"){
                        _("status").innerHTML = "gotcha";
                } 
                else {
                        _("status").innerHTML = "not now";
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("email="+email+"&pass="+pass+"&pass1="+pass1);
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

           <form id="passchanger" onsubmit="return false;">
           <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Login Email for verification" /> 
           <input id="pass" type="password" placeholder="Old password" /> 
           <input id="pass1" type="password" placeholder="New password" /> 
           <input id="pass2" type="password" placeholder="Confirm password" />
           <button id="passbtn" onclick="paschange()">Log In</button> 
           <p id="status"></p>                      
            </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one thing i am missing here:
at the beginning of your php code, there's a line

```
if(isset($_GET["u"])){
```

asking for a GET parameter called 'u'
in your javascript code i do not see any reference to that paramter being passed to the ajax-request (i might be missing it, sorry if that's the case)

if that parameter is not passed to the ajax-request, the code between this line and the closing '}' just before the html starts is never executed, and therefor has no response (only the html, since a line with 'exit()' on it is also never executed)

overall, your code looks fine to me

Comment: I have removed the u parameter also. Now its showing not now.

Comment: something that has helped me a lot, is debugging. try to display the value of various variables (in PHP, use echo, print, print_r of var_dump, in javascript, you could use alert) or use the debugging functions in your browser to do the same of to see the response of the ajax-request

Comment: same i did.. i echoed all the post variables declared in php. They are displaying correctly. Dont know whats going wrong

Comment: maybe a stupid question: have you done the same for your javascript code, e.g. checking the actual response text?